# Dropdown not working in Contact Form 7

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have added a contact form using the plugin **contact form 7** with drop-down area.

http://www.edsys.in/contact/ [1](http://www.edsys.in/contact/)

The trial software field has the dropdown.But it s not displayin properly.

T searched over net and applied the following css:

```
select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

...but it didnt work.

I need something like this: http://www.zebraprintandcopy.com/upload-file/

When I checked the source code, I couldn't find any helpful styles.

Thanks in advance!!

**edit:**

This is the code I have added for the dropdown in the form:

```
<p>Trial Software Of : <br />[select* dropdown multiple "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"]</p>
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to create the field in CF7. Remove "multiple" from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to uncheck the option "Allow multiple answers" when you create the field. Or you can remove the "multiple" option from the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **multiple** from your select box code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `multiple` option from the form, in the Admin.

Right now, you likely have something like:

```
[select your-select multiple "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"]
```

Read the [docs](http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like the following with "multiple" removed.

`<p>Trial Software Of : <br />[select* dropdown "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4"]</p>`